# symfony 2 admin setup error

Tags: symfony, installation, admin

When I'm trying to setup admin in console:

```
php app/console admin:setup
```

I'm getting an error:

```
ParameterNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent parameter "twig.form.resources".
```

I tried to add twig.form.resources parameter in config.yml, but it didn't help =(

```
twig:
    form:
         resources: 
                - 'GeneratorBundle::fields.html.twig'
```

What is the problem? thanks

Comment: I couldn't find any answer, so I used SonataAdminBundle which worked well.

Answer (score 0):

defining stuff in the config.yml does not define parameters.

in oder to define parameters, you need to put them in parameters.ini (symfony 2.0) or in the parameters.yml (2.1) or set them in a dependency injection extension.